# the choice for video capture in Mac OSX?

Tags: c++, macos, webcam

What is the best choice for webcam video/image capture under Mac OSX with C/C++? It seems that Apple recommended QTKit, but it is a Objective-C library. Any sample code to do the job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Objective-C library from your C++ program indirectly. Just create a C interface to the Objective-C functions and compile it with your Objective-C compiler.

Answer (score 0):

It mostly depend what kind of application you are looking,

OSX Cocoa framework provides plenty of choices,

for video streaming : [AVCaptureSession](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureSession_Class/) it provides you to configure image resolutions, if you have more then one camera attached through USB, it provides you option to choose camera

Moreover with this class you can choose frame rate , format type , Qos

for simple image processing , which gives you RGB frame go for qt framework.